# How to efficiently use boost graph

Tags: c++, boost, graph, graphviz, boost-graph

I have the following piece of code:

```
struct Vertex {
std::string name;
};

struct Edge {
std::string name;
};

class MyGraph {
public:
  MyGraph() = default;

  using Graph = adjacency_list<vecS, vecS, bidirectionalS,
                               std::shared_ptr<Vertex>, std::shared_ptr<Edge>>;
  using VertexDesc = graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor;
  using EdgeDesc = graph_traits<Graph>::edge_descriptor;

  void addNode(std::shared_ptr<Vertex> node){
    const auto name = node->name;

    if (vertexMap_.find(name) == vertexMap_.end()) {
      const auto vertex = add_vertex(node, graph_);
      vertexLabelArray_.emplace_back(name);
      vertexMap_[name] = vertex;
    }
  }
  void addEdge(std::shared_ptr<Vertex> src, std::shared_ptr<Vertex> dst, std::shared_ptr<Edge> weight = nullptr) {

  const auto srcName = src->name;
  const auto dstName = dst->name;

  const auto vertexPair = std::make_pair(srcName, dstName);

    if (edgeSet_.find(vertexPair) == edgeSet_.end()) {
        addNode(src);
        addNode(dst);
        const auto edge = add_edge(vertexMap_[srcName], vertexMap_[dstName], weight, graph_).first;
        edgeSet_.insert(vertexPair);
        edgeLabelMap_[edge] = weight ? weight->name : "";

    }
  }
  void print(std::ostream& out)
  {
    write_graphviz(out, graph_, 
        make_label_writer(vertexLabelArray_.data()), 
        make_label_writer(make_assoc_property_map(edgeLabelMap_)));
  }


private:
  std::vector<std::string> vertexLabelArray_;
  std::map<EdgeDesc, std::string> edgeLabelMap_;
  std::map<std::string, VertexDesc> vertexMap_;
  std::set<std::pair<std::string, std::string>> edgeSet_;
  Graph graph_;
};


struct Node : Vertex {};
struct Arc : Edge {};

int main() {
    MyGraph g;

    const auto n1 = std::make_shared<Node>(Node{{"n1"}});
    const auto n2 = std::make_shared<Node>(Node{{"n2"}});
    const auto e1 = std::make_shared<Arc>(Arc{{"e1"}});

    g.addEdge(n1, n2, e1);

    g.print(std::cout);

}
```

I would like to reduce some of the potential redundancies:

1 - how can i use `setS` instead of `vecS` to avoid checking is a vertex/edge exists. when i do so, the `write_graphiz` function complains that it fails with lots of errors beginning with

- `error: cannot form a reference to 'void' typedef const value_type& const_reference;`

2 - i am using a shared_ptr for allowing for custom object to be attached to vertices and edges. is there an easy way for looking up a vertex index based on its attached object?

3 - Is it possible to remove most of the external data structures and use boost property instead somehow?

the whole thing is uploaded here: https://godbolt.org/z/qbEnEoYj3

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1 - how can i use setS instead of vecS to avoid checking is a
> ***Q.:*** vertex/edge exists. when i do so, the write_graphiz function complains
> that it fails with lots of errors beginning with

Sure. In fact the edge selector is no problem to begin with:  https://godbolt.org/z/b1xbYMM4s. Making the vertex containter `setS` won't do what you mean, because every added vertex is unique by definition.

But in the interest of showing the technical issue at hand: there is no implicit vertex index (ordinal numbering [0..numvertices()) for that storage strategy. Some algorithms require one. Also, you assume one with `VertexLabelArray_` which no longer makes sense, so let's change into `VertexLabelMap_` just like for edge labels:

**[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/nadz6MxG1)**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graphviz.hpp>

struct Vertex {
    std::string name;
};

struct Edge {
    std::string name;
};

class MyGraph {
public:
    MyGraph() = default;

    using Graph      = boost::adjacency_list< //
        boost::setS, boost::listS, boost::bidirectionalS,
        std::shared_ptr<Vertex>, std::shared_ptr<Edge>>;
    using VertexDesc = boost::graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor;
    using EdgeDesc   = boost::graph_traits<Graph>::edge_descriptor;

    void addNode(std::shared_ptr<Vertex> node)
    {
        const auto name = node->name;

        if (vertexMap_.find(name) == vertexMap_.end()) {
            const auto vertex = add_vertex(node, graph_);
            vertexLabelMap_.emplace(vertex, name);
            vertexMap_[name] = vertex;
        }
    }

    void addEdge(std::shared_ptr<Vertex> src, std::shared_ptr<Vertex> dst,
                std::shared_ptr<Edge> weight = nullptr)
    {
        const auto srcName = src->name;
        const auto dstName = dst->name;

        const auto vertexPair = std::make_pair(srcName, dstName);

        if (edgeSet_.find(vertexPair) == edgeSet_.end()) {
            addNode(src);
            addNode(dst);
            const auto edge = add_edge(vertexMap_[srcName], vertexMap_[dstName],
                                    weight, graph_)
                                .first;
            edgeSet_.insert(vertexPair);
            edgeLabelMap_[edge] = weight ? weight->name : "";
        }
    }

    void print(std::ostream& out)
    {
        std::map<VertexDesc, int> idmap;

        for (auto v : boost::make_iterator_range(vertices(graph_))) {
            idmap.emplace(v, idmap.size());
        }
        write_graphviz(out, graph_,
                    boost::make_label_writer(
                        boost::make_assoc_property_map(vertexLabelMap_)),
                    boost::make_label_writer(
                        boost::make_assoc_property_map(edgeLabelMap_)),
                    boost::default_writer{},
                    boost::make_assoc_property_map(idmap));
    }

private:
    std::map<VertexDesc, std::string>             vertexLabelMap_;
    std::map<EdgeDesc, std::string>               edgeLabelMap_;
    std::map<std::string, VertexDesc>             vertexMap_;
    std::set<std::pair<std::string, std::string>> edgeSet_;
    Graph                                         graph_;
};

struct Node : Vertex {};
struct Arc : Edge {};

#include <iostream>
int main() {
    MyGraph g;

    const auto n1 = std::make_shared<Node>(Node{{"n1"}});
    const auto n2 = std::make_shared<Node>(Node{{"n2"}});
    const auto e1 = std::make_shared<Arc>(Arc{{"e1"}});

    g.addEdge(n1, n2, e1);

    g.print(std::cout);

}
```

Alternatively, if such an index can be made part of `Vertex`:

**[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/rPYdaj171)**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graphviz.hpp>
#include <boost/property_map/transform_value_property_map.hpp>

struct Vertex {
    int id;
    std::string name;
};

struct Edge {
    std::string name;
};

class MyGraph {
public:
    MyGraph() = default;

    using Graph      = boost::adjacency_list< //
        boost::setS, boost::listS, boost::bidirectionalS,
        std::shared_ptr<Vertex>, std::shared_ptr<Edge>>;
    using VertexDesc = boost::graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor;
    using EdgeDesc   = boost::graph_traits<Graph>::edge_descriptor;

    void addNode(std::shared_ptr<Vertex> const& node)
    {
        const auto name = node->name;

        if (vertexMap_.find(name) == vertexMap_.end()) {
            const auto vertex = add_vertex(node, graph_);
            vertexLabelArray_.push_back(name);
            vertexMap_[name] = vertex;
        }
    }

    void addEdge(std::shared_ptr<Vertex> const& src,
                std::shared_ptr<Vertex> const& dst,
                std::shared_ptr<Edge> const&   weight = nullptr)
    {
        const auto srcName = src->name;
        const auto dstName = dst->name;

        const auto vertexPair = std::make_pair(srcName, dstName);

        if (edgeSet_.find(vertexPair) == edgeSet_.end()) {
            addNode(src);
            addNode(dst);
            const auto edge = add_edge(vertexMap_[srcName], vertexMap_[dstName],
                                    weight, graph_)
                                .first;
            edgeSet_.insert(vertexPair);
            edgeLabelMap_[edge] = weight ? weight->name : "";
        }
    }

    void print(std::ostream& out)
    {
        auto idmap = boost::make_transform_value_property_map(
                [](auto const& sp) { return sp->id; },
                get(boost::vertex_bundle, graph_));

        write_graphviz(
            out, graph_,
            boost::make_label_writer(boost::make_iterator_property_map(
                vertexLabelArray_.begin(), idmap)),
            boost::make_label_writer(
                boost::make_assoc_property_map(edgeLabelMap_)),
            boost::default_writer{}, idmap);
    }

private:
    std::vector<std::string>                      vertexLabelArray_;
    std::map<EdgeDesc, std::string>               edgeLabelMap_;
    std::map<std::string, VertexDesc>             vertexMap_;
    std::set<std::pair<std::string, std::string>> edgeSet_;
    Graph                                         graph_;
};

struct Node : Vertex {};
struct Arc : Edge {};

#include <iostream>
int main() {
    MyGraph g;

    const auto n1 = std::make_shared<Node>(Node{{0, "n1"}});
    const auto n2 = std::make_shared<Node>(Node{{1, "n2"}});
    const auto e1 = std::make_shared<Arc>(Arc{{"e1"}});

    g.addEdge(n1, n2, e1);

    g.print(std::cout);

}
```

> ***Q.:*** 2 - i am using a shared_ptr for allowing for custom object to be
> attached to vertices and edges.

I noticed this. I think it's a little bit questionable. If you're looking for efficiency, I wouldn't be using shared_ptr all over the place.

> ***Q.:*** is there an easy way for looking up a
> vertex index based on its attached object?

Not built in. There is the (undocumented?) `labeled_graph` adaptor that has... some convenience. YMMV. Also, you can *[use a `bimap` or similar](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a85371%20boost%20graph%20bimap)*.

> ***Q.:*** 3 - Is it possible to remove most of the external data structures and
> use boost property instead somehow?

I would strongly consider this. Of course you can. Basically, you already do this.

### Review

Your code has many opportunities for improvement (including effective optimizations).

0. pass the shared pointers by `const&`:
1. do not pass shared pointers in the first place, since you're not intending to share ownership/observe refcounts/lifetimes. I'll show this when I show a version that embodies the node/edge data in the graph model directly.
2. `void addNode` could return the vertex descriptor, avoiding a lot of redundant lookups. This also makes it more explicit about an item already existing not being an error. (Right now it simply ignores the `addNode`/`addEdge`?)

   ```
   void ensureEdge(std::shared_ptr<Vertex> const& src,
                   std::shared_ptr<Vertex> const& dst,
                   std::shared_ptr<Edge> const&   edge = {})
   {
       if (edgeSet_.emplace(src->name, dst->name).second) {
           auto [descriptor, isnew] = add_edge( //
               ensureNode(src), ensureNode(dst), edge, graph_);

           edgeLabelMap_.emplace(descriptor, edge ? edge->name : "");
       }
   }
   ```

   Doing  less work means being more efficient.
3. Like you almost mentioned you can already test whether an edge exists using the result of `add_edge`, obviating the extra `edgeSet_`:

   ```
   EdgeDesc ensureEdge(std::shared_ptr<Vertex> const& src,
                       std::shared_ptr<Vertex> const& dst,
                       std::shared_ptr<Edge> const&   edge = {})
   {
       auto [descriptor, isnew] =
           add_edge(ensureNode(src), ensureNode(dst), edge, graph_);

       if (isnew)
           edgeLabelMap_.emplace(descriptor, edge ? edge->name : "");

       return descriptor;
   }
   ```

   Note that now, because the behaviour is more consistent, we can also return the edge descriptor. This will remove the need to query for the edge we just added.

Current version **[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/faWKoqjjE)**:

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graphviz.hpp>
#include <boost/property_map/transform_value_property_map.hpp>

struct Vertex { std::string name; };
struct Edge   { std::string name; };
class MyGraph {
public:
    MyGraph() = default;

    using Graph      = boost::adjacency_list< //
        boost::setS, boost::vecS, boost::bidirectionalS,
        std::shared_ptr<Vertex>, std::shared_ptr<Edge>>;
    using VertexDesc = Graph::vertex_descriptor;
    using EdgeDesc   = Graph::edge_descriptor;

    VertexDesc ensureNode(std::shared_ptr<Vertex> const& node)
    {
        auto const& name = node->name;

        auto it = vertexMap_.find(name);
        if (it == vertexMap_.end()) {
            auto descriptor = add_vertex(node, graph_);
            vertexLabelArray_.push_back(name);
            vertexMap_[name] = descriptor;
            it = vertexMap_.emplace(name, descriptor).first;
        }

        return it->second;
    }

    EdgeDesc ensureEdge(std::shared_ptr<Vertex> const& src,
                        std::shared_ptr<Vertex> const& dst,
                        std::shared_ptr<Edge> const&   edge = {})
    {
        auto [descriptor, isnew] =
            add_edge(ensureNode(src), ensureNode(dst), edge, graph_);

        if (isnew)
            edgeLabelMap_.emplace(descriptor, edge ? edge->name : "");

        return descriptor;
    }

    void print(std::ostream& out) const
    {
        write_graphviz(
            out, graph_, //
            boost::make_label_writer(vertexLabelArray_.data()),
            boost::make_label_writer(make_assoc_property_map(edgeLabelMap_)));
    }

private:
    std::vector<std::string>          vertexLabelArray_;
    std::map<EdgeDesc, std::string>   edgeLabelMap_;
    std::map<std::string, VertexDesc> vertexMap_;
    Graph                             graph_;
};

struct Node : Vertex {};
struct Arc : Edge {};

#include <iostream>
int main() {
    MyGraph g;

    const auto n1 = std::make_shared<Node>(Node{{"n1"}});
    const auto n2 = std::make_shared<Node>(Node{{"n2"}});
    const auto e1 = std::make_shared<Arc>(Arc{{"e1"}});

    g.ensureEdge(n1, n2, e1);
    g.print(std::cout);
}
```

Still prints

```
digraph G {
0[label=n2];
1[label=n1];
1->0 [label=e1];
}
```

### Other Steps

1. You specified `BidirectionalGraph` support, but don't currently use the in-edge interface. Consider dropping that so  you don't incur the overhead for maintaining the redundant edge information

   ```
   using Graph      = boost::adjacency_list< //
       boost::setS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS,
       std::shared_ptr<Vertex>, std::shared_ptr<Edge>>;
   ```
2. Consider using value semantics for the property bundles. This will reduce allocations, increase locality of reference and may enable a host of storage optimization opportunities.

   Consider this version, which no longer uses `vertexLabelArray_` nor `edgeLabelMap_` (both properties simply reside inside the graph model after all):

   ```
   void print(std::ostream& out) const {
       write_graphviz(out, graph_,
                      make_label_writer(get(&Vertex::name, graph_)),
                      make_label_writer(get(&Edge::name, graph_)));
   }
   ```

**[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/Mrdcx8bbW)**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graphviz.hpp>

struct Vertex { std::string name; };
struct Edge   { std::string name; };

class MyGraph {
public:
    using Graph      = boost::adjacency_list< //
        boost::setS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, Vertex, Edge>;
    using VertexDesc = Graph::vertex_descriptor;
    using EdgeDesc   = Graph::edge_descriptor;

    VertexDesc ensureNode(Vertex const& node) {
        if (auto it = vertexMap_.find(node.name); it != vertexMap_.end())
            return it->second;

        auto descriptor       = add_vertex(node, graph_);
        vertexMap_[node.name] = descriptor;
        vertexMap_.emplace(node.name, descriptor);
        return descriptor;
    }

    EdgeDesc ensureEdge(Vertex const& src, Vertex const& dst, Edge edge) {
        auto [descriptor, isnew] =
            add_edge(ensureNode(src), ensureNode(dst), std::move(edge), graph_);
        return descriptor; // TODO maybe raise an error if !isnew?
    }

    void print(std::ostream& out) const {
        write_graphviz(out, graph_,
                    make_label_writer(get(&Vertex::name, graph_)),
                    make_label_writer(get(&Edge::name, graph_)));
    }
private:
    std::map<std::string, VertexDesc> vertexMap_;
    Graph graph_;
};

struct Node : Vertex { };
struct Arc : Edge { };

#include <iostream>
int main() {
    MyGraph g;

    Node n1{{"n1"}}, n2{{"n2"}};
    Arc  e1{{"e1"}};

    g.ensureEdge(n1, n2, e1);
    g.ensureEdge({"n3"}, {"n4"}, {"e2"});
    g.print(std::cout);
}
```

Prints

```
digraph G {
0[label=n2];
1[label=n1];
2[label=n4];
3[label=n3];
1->0 [label=e1];
3->2 [label=e2];
}
```

### Much More Efficient Vertex Lookup?

If you really care about storage and lookup efficiency, make `vertexMap_` key a `string_view`. This requires careful thought about the lifetime of the referred-to strings.

```
// use stored property, not parameter as vertexMap_ key!
vertexMap_.emplace(graph_[vd].name, vd);
```

For starters, you **NEED** a container selector with *reference stabiility* for the vertex container (e.g. `listS`).

Also, consider making the container a `flat_map` so storage and lookup will be much optimized. They will effectively become `vector<tuple<char const*, size_t, size_t> >`:

```
boost::container::flat_map<std::string_view, VertexDesc> vertexMap_;
```

See It [Live On Compiler Explorer](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/c8d99TzWh)

```
#include <boost/container/flat_map.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graphviz.hpp>

struct Vertex { std::string name; };
struct Edge   { std::string name; };

class MyGraph {
public:
    using Graph      = boost::adjacency_list< //
        boost::setS, boost::listS, boost::directedS, Vertex, Edge>;
    using VertexDesc = Graph::vertex_descriptor;
    using EdgeDesc   = Graph::edge_descriptor;

    VertexDesc ensureNode(Vertex const& node) {
        if (auto it = vertexMap_.find(node.name); it != vertexMap_.end())
            return it->second;

        auto vd = add_vertex(node, graph_);
        // use stored property, not parameter as vertexMap_ key!
        vertexMap_.emplace(graph_[vd].name, vd);
        return vd;
    }

    EdgeDesc ensureEdge(Vertex const& src, Vertex const& dst, Edge edge) {
        auto [ed, isnew] =
            add_edge(ensureNode(src), ensureNode(dst), std::move(edge), graph_);
        return ed; // TODO maybe raise an error if !isnew?
    }

    void print(std::ostream& out) const {
        write_graphviz(out, graph_,
                    make_label_writer(get(&Vertex::name, graph_)),
                    make_label_writer(get(&Edge::name, graph_)),
                    boost::default_writer{},
                    get(&Vertex::name, graph_));
    }

private:
    boost::container::flat_map<std::string_view, VertexDesc> vertexMap_;
    Graph graph_;
};

struct Node : Vertex { };
struct Arc : Edge { };

#include <iostream>
int main() {
    MyGraph g;

    Node n1{{"n1"}}, n2{{"n2"}};
    Arc  e1{{"e1"}};

    g.ensureEdge(n1, n2, e1);
    g.ensureEdge({"n3"}, {"n4"}, {"e2"});
    g.print(std::cout);
}
```

Note this cheated a **little** by using the Vertex `name` as the graphviz node ID. That makes a lot of sense anyways:

```
digraph G {
n2[label=n2];
n1[label=n1];
n4[label=n4];
n3[label=n3];
n1->n2 [label=e1];
n3->n4 [label=e2];
}
```

If you insist on integral IDs - you can hack them back using the fact that `vertexMap_` is now contiguous:

```
void print(std::ostream& out) const {
    auto node_id = boost::make_function_property_map<VertexDesc>(
        [this](VertexDesc vd) {
            return vertexMap_.find(graph_[vd].name) - vertexMap_.begin();
        });
    write_graphviz(out, graph_,
                   make_label_writer(get(&Vertex::name, graph_)),
                   make_label_writer(get(&Edge::name, graph_)),
                   boost::default_writer{}, node_id);
}
```

This prints ([Live Link](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/41sTM6bWs)):

```
digraph G {
1[label=n2];
0[label=n1];
3[label=n4];
2[label=n3];
0->1 [label=e1];
2->3 [label=e2];
}
```

> **Note** that doing the `listS` vertex container selection makes a BIG difference in resource trade-offs in the graph implementation itself, so if the vertex lookup via `vertexMap_` is **not** your bottleneck, don't do this optimization!

### More BGL facilities

As I mentioned there's some supported for labeled graphs in BGL. I'm not recommending that as I've [run into my share of implementation bugs/quirks](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a85371%20labeled_graph). But I would be remiss not to mention it here.

Also see [How to create a named_graph with Boost Graph Library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10540338/how-to-create-a-named-graph-with-boost-graph-library/10653326#10653326) which is a very good answer

Comment: Thanks a lot! i see youre using setS but still doing checks to see if a vertex exists. why do you do this? isnt the idea behind using setS to not do that? also, you changed from shared_ptr to using types directly. the reason for having the pointer was to allow for inherited objects. in my case the objects are not as simple as you see in this example and thats why i wanted inheritance. lastly, do you have a version where i could get rid of all extra data structures? im looking for a way to use `propertry<std::shared_ptr<Vertex>>` or similar within the graph definition.

Comment: 1. I never used `setS` for vertices and I stated explicitly why: [_Making the
vertex containter setS won't do what you mean, because every added vertex is
unique by
definition._](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69726572/how-to-efficiently-use-boost-graph#:~:text=Making%20the%20vertex%20containter%20setS%20won%27t%20do%20what%20you%20mean%2C%20because%20every%20added%20vertex%20is%20unique%20by%20definition)

Comment: 2. I stated why. You're free to use inheritance if you insist, but your
question specifically asks ["How to _efficiently_ use boost graph"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69726572/how-to-efficiently-use-boost-graph#:~:text=How%20to%20efficiently%20use%20boost%20graph) and _"Is it possible to remove most of the external data structures and use boost property instead".

Comment: 3. I tried to take things with small steps in my answer. The downside is
perhaps it became long and complex. Perhaps some steps were still too big. I
got rid of all of `edgeSet_`, `vertexLabelArray_` and `edgeLabelMap_`. The
`make_transform_value_property_map` application shows how to use properties
from `Vertex` even when stored in `shared_ptr`. Does that help?

Comment: To make it concrete https://godbolt.org/z/zbM31E7qx. I took the opportunity to rename `Vertex` to `VertexProps` - just to clarify that `im looking for a way to use propertry<std::shared_ptr<Vertex>>` was already exactly what you had from the start.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your patience and detailed explanation and sorry i missed some of the parts. i got a bit lost :) 
so, to clarify the point for using setS or any other format is just for ordering the vertices/edges? it has no effect on the actual insertion functionality? how about using setS for edges?

Comment: And another question, what is point of using boost::property? i.e. `boost::adjacency_list<boost::setS, boost::listS, boost::directedS, boost::property<boost::vertex_index_t, VertexProps>, boost::property<boost::edge_index_t, EdgeProps>>;`

Comment: Also, what is the role of `mapper` here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238611/discussion-between-sehe-and-katetsu).